# Can the same socket be used for server and client?

Tags: sockets, client-server

I put a TCP server and client code in PIC controller. Now just wanted to know, can the same device run both client and server at sametime? And if possible can we use the same socket on a TCP stack for server and for client?

Comment: What do you mean by both client and server?  A TCP stack just handles sockets.  You can use the same socket for whatever you want, as long as your protocol handles it.

Comment: Also, are you perhaps confusing _ports_ and _sockets_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question about using the same socket doesn't really make any sense since presumably the client and the server are separate processes, so they cannot share the exact same socket. For a server, you usually create a socket, then `bind` it to a specific port, and `accept` connections. For the client, you create a socket, and `connect` to a specified address (an IP address and port pair for a TCP/IP connection).

The same device can run a TCP server and client at the same time. You can start the server listening on a specific port and then connect the client to the same port, and the two programs will communicate with each other.